# How to get top 1 from each group

Tags: sql, informix

This is specific for IBM informix

I have a table with an id and a datetime (pluss more but they are included)

Each id have multiple entries of different datetimes, and I want the top result from each id sorted by datetime.

I tried this:

```
SELECT FIRST 1 * FROM Table WHERE id IN (32,33,35,36,37,50,51) ORDER BY datetime
```

This, of course, give me one result - the top datetime from one of the id's. I would like to get one result from each id.

Is there an easy solution for this or do I need to create a selection for each id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from table t1
join
(
  SELECT id, max(datetime) as dt
  FROM Table 
  WHERE id IN (32,33,35,36,37,50,51) 
  GROUP BY id
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.datetime = t2.dt
ORDER BY t1.datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

The juergen code is correct and it has good performance.

And i have another query also
try this

```
 Create Table Sample1(id Int,mydate Datetime )
 Declare @DateTime Datetime =getdate()

 Insert into Sample1 Values(1,getdate())
 Insert into Sample1 Values(1,DateAdd(MI,1,getdate()))
 Insert into Sample1 Values(1,DateAdd(MI,2,getdate()))
 Insert into Sample1 Values(1,DateAdd(MI,3,getdate()))
 Insert into Sample1 Values(2,getdate())
 Insert into Sample1 Values(2,DateAdd(MI,1,getdate()))
 Insert into Sample1 Values(2,DateAdd(MI,2,getdate()))
 Insert into Sample1 Values(2,DateAdd(MI,3,getdate()))
 Insert into Sample1 Values(3,getdate())
 Insert into Sample1 Values(3,DateAdd(MI,1,getdate()))
 Insert into Sample1 Values(3,DateAdd(MI,2,getdate()))
 Insert into Sample1 Values(3,DateAdd(MI,3,getdate()))

 select id,mydate from 
 (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition by Id Order by mydate desc) as dt,id,mydate
   FROM Sample1  
 ) A Where dt=1

 Drop Table Sample1
```

Thanks

Comment: The question states at the very top: "This is specific for IBM Informix". Your answer is for SQL Server, and will not help the OP.